# How to build a small LED assembly?

Tags: led, batteries, switches

I'm building a custom model of the AT-ST from The Mandalorian:

[image: Mandalorian AT-ST Raider]

I have the model almost done and I thought it would be really cool to add actual lighting to it.  The model is about 6" (16cm) tall, but I have a usable space of about 1.5" X 2" (3.8cm X 5.0cm).

My idea is to add 1-3 LED red Christmas light bulbs to the interior and one white LED bulb for the search light.  It should be attached to a on/off switch and powered by LR44 or similar sized batteries.

The problem is my Google powers are failing me.  I haven't been able to find the components needed for this project. So, my list of components (feel free to suggest a better solution):

**Bulbs:**  I mentioned LED Xmas light bulbs and I've found those easily. If anyone knows a better solution, please let me know.

**On/Off Switch:** The model is somewhat fragile, so I'd like the switch to be the slider-toggle style rather than a push button switch.  What is a good part for this?

**Battery holder:**  I mentioned LR44, but a different battery might be better.  From my understanding, the XMAS light bulbs use 2.5V, so I'd need 2-3 batteries to power my plan. What is this part called?

If this question is too simple for SE:EE, please let me know the proper exchange.

Comment: You need resistors in series with the LEDs to ensure they don't burn out.  If you prefer you can just buy red and cool white LEDs from digikey, aliexpress or ebay rather than cutting up a strand of christmas lights and it may be easier to build them into your project.

Comment: @K H:  Thanks. What resistance do I need to match a typical LED?

Comment: Did you ever build this?

Answer (score 0):

A Christmas string LED is not the best choice. Digikey has thousands of different LEDs and switches. Learn to use the filters. Avoid *surface mount* parts (harder for a beginner).

For LEDs, you probably want *through hole* parts. A common size is about 0.2" dia.

For the switch, you probably want *slide*, *panel mount*. Here is one possibility:
https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cw-industries/GF-126-0135/CWI437-ND

An appropriate battery holder for a coin cell may be the hardest item to find. Most are designed to be soldered to a printed wiring board and the board helps contain the battery.

I have keychain LED lights that don't use resistors, but unless you get a good match between the battery voltage and the LED voltage, it is best to use a resistor. LEDs are highly non-linear, the current is not proportional to the voltage, and the current is what you want to control.

It is hard to pick a resistor value without knowing how may volts your battery will be, and which LED you are using (different colors drop different voltages). You want a separate series resistor for each LED, LEDs in parallel do not share current well. A common LED is rated for 10-20 milliamps, but will light fairly well with only 1-2 milliamps. You want to be on the low-end so your battery will last.

[image]

http://lednique.com/current-voltage-relationships/iv-curves/

Pick your desired current on the left, and draw a horizontal line until it intersects the LED curve. Then draw a vertical line and see what the voltage drop will be. At 5 mA, white LEDs *drop* about 2.4V and red LEDs *drop* about 1.6V. Use the curve supplied with the actual part you have chosen if possible, but this generic curve will get you close.

Series_Resistor = (Battery_Voltage - LED_Voltage_Drop) / Desired_Current

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuw5K5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I won't attempt to duplicate how to calculate resistors or how to wire an LED, this site and many sites online show how to do that.

If you have a model that demands a very tiny source of light, you can purchase 0402 (0.04" x 0.02") = 0.5 x 0.35mm or bulkier 0603 LEDs with wires pre-attached from the usual Asian sources. Amazon may have some as well.

It's not impossible to buy the LEDs yourself from an electronics distributor such as Digikey and source very thin wire and attach the leads yourself under a magnifier or microscope (and you might get higher quality LEDs that way) but it's not super easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reproduce the feel of a searchlight in a small package, you need a LED with a tight beam. Beam angle depends on optics, and on a 5mm LED, optics is the transparent plastic package.

So, go to [mouser](https://www.mouser.fr/Optoelectronics/LED-Emitters/Standard-LEDs-Through-Hole/_/N-ec21l) and sort on beam angle. You can also sort on candela, since this is light power divided by beam angle (ie, lm/sr). A LED with a high candela number will tend to have a tight bright beam.